# Dockerfile from python:3.6-slim add jdk8

Tags: docker, java-8, dockerfile

someone could help me, i'm starting from follow docker file

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils build-essential gcc
```

And i would add an openjdk 8

thanks

Comment: In most cases you'd build a separate image `FROM openjdk:8`, and use a tool like Docker Compose to run both containers together.

Comment: i need python3 and jdk 8 in the same docker container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download java tar.gz, unpack it and set environment variable.
Below a sample of implementation in Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils build-essential gcc

ENV JAVA_FOLDER java-se-8u41-ri

ENV JVM_ROOT /usr/lib/jvm

ENV JAVA_PKG_NAME openjdk-8u41-b04-linux-x64-14_jan_2020.tar.gz
ENV JAVA_TAR_GZ_URL https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8u41/ri/$JAVA_PKG_NAME

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*    && \
    apt-get clean                                                               && \
    apt-get autoremove                                                          && \
    echo Downloading $JAVA_TAR_GZ_URL                                           && \
    wget -q $JAVA_TAR_GZ_URL                                                    && \
    tar -xvf $JAVA_PKG_NAME                                                     && \
    rm $JAVA_PKG_NAME                                                           && \
    mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm                                                       && \
    mv ./$JAVA_FOLDER $JVM_ROOT                                                 && \
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java $JVM_ROOT/$JAVA_FOLDER/bin/java 1        && \
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac $JVM_ROOT/$JAVA_FOLDER/bin/javac 1     && \
    java -version
```

Answer (score 4):

In cases where you need `python` and `java` installed in a same image (i.e. `pyspark`) I find it easier to extend the `openjdk` images with `python` than the other way around for example:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        python3.7 \
        python3-pip \
        python3.7-dev \
        python3-setuptools \
        python3-wheel
```

Build the image: `docker build --rm -t so:64051125 .`

[image: Python + Java versions]

**Note**: the version of `python3` available through `apt` on `debian:buster-slim` is `3.7`, if you really need `3.6` could try [building it from source](https://devguide.python.org/setup/).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, but i need jdk8 and python3.6 in the same container.

Comment: Hence the note, you'd probably need to build `python3.6` from source. If you extend `python:3.6-slim-buster` image then you have `openjdk-11-jdk` available in `apt`, if you extend the `openjdk:8-jdk-slim-buster` image then you have `python3.7` available in `apt`. Given your specific requirements you'll possibly need to build one or the other or both from source.

Answer (score 1):

Up to today (17/02/2021) `openjdk-8-jdk` is still in debian 9 (Strech) but removed from debian 10 (Buster), so you should find `openjdk-8-jdk` if you use this python docker image: `python:3.6-stretch` instead of `python:3.6-slim-buster`