# Docker: base image for a Java+Python application

Tags: java, python, docker

I'm preparing a docker image for an application that includes both Java and Python components. There are a few ways to go about the base image, and I was wondering if there's one "correct", or canonical way:

1. Start from a **JDK** image and add Python using apt-get
2. Start from a **Python** image and add JDK using apt-get
3. Start from a minimal Ubuntu/Debian/CentOS and add Python and OpenJDK using apt-get/yum

I can't think of even one reason to prefer #1 over #2 or vice-versa; however, I believe #3 will include many things I don't need.

**EDIT** while the question at [Dockerfile from python:3.6-slim add jdk8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051125) has two possible solutions, I was looking to know if there's a best practice, or canonical answer.

Comment: You provide more details, what is going to run on that piece of container? If you only aim at one but just need the other during build time, [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) might be a good solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dockerfile from python:3.6-slim add jdk8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051125/dockerfile-from-python3-6-slim-add-jdk8)

Comment: I find it easier to [extend a `openjdk` image with `python`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64052768/1423507) but to each their own.

Comment: If you can, two separate containers would be the "most correct".  (But it's not necessarily possible or reasonable.)

Comment: @masseyb thank you for the linked answer; still, I wonder why you think it's easier to start from Java and add Python, and not the other way around.

Comment: Question of preference, to each their own. I don’t like installing openjdk.

Comment: @masseyb both openjdk and python are installable via apt-get, no need to mess with sources; hence my search for answer: why is it easy to go this way, why do you dislike installing openjdk? I totally understand the "question of preference" part, though.

Comment: More familiar with installing python, more experience dealing with python, pip, etc. Just easier for me, no difference in the end really.